# Unexpectedly changes in MR

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, merge-request

in Gitlab:

1. Created a new branch called `xxx` from prod.
2. Coding in the `XXX`（2 changes）
3. Created a new branch called `merge_XXX_dev` from `dev`.
4. Pull from `XXX` to `merge_XXX_dev` and commit the changes（2 changes）
5. Created a MR (`merge_XXX_dev` to `dev`) and ask other team to admit it (2 changes)

2 Days later when my MR turns there were 194 changes in my MR(during the 2 Days other team’s changes appeared too)

I want to know the reason and how to avoid it again.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does "when my MR turns" mean? Was it merged, rebased, or something else? From which branch(es)?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  
I have to ask the MR team(which responsible for admit merge request) to merge my changes from 'merge_xxx_dev' branch to the 'dev' branch.   
There's a lot MR to ask the MR team to admit.    
for example,  
my MR is NO.123,the MR team has to admit NO.1~NO.122 then my MR turns.
Now the problem is when i create the MR, there's only my changes(2 changes),
But 2Days later when the MR team see,there's 194 changes(include NO.1~NO.122's changes)

Comment: So you mean when it's that MR's "turn" to get reviewed :-) It sounds like you just need to rebase your MR on top of the target branch `dev`. Otherwise its changes will be to cancel out whatever other users have done since you originally made your commits.

Comment: The problem is I don't know when the MR team admit my MR, I can make sure my MR is the top of the target branch dev when I create it, but the time of MR team review it is out of my control.

Comment: What is "admit an MR"? Do you mean "submit" or do you mean "approve"?

Comment: yeah,"admit an MR" means "approve"

Comment: I found that there's two version in my MR,but it only had been changed once.  
and the strange thing is the two version have the same hash.  (the hash which should have 2 changes)
version 1 is my changes, latest version include 3month earlier's changes, 5month earlier's changes, even 7month earlier's changes